Unreal Engine ChaosVehicle Plugin: Car is floating and tires are rotating in every direction
I tried implementing a small game with Vehicles in Unreal with the Sample SportsCar from the standard vehicle project. I used the ChaosVehicle Plugin as described in this tutorial: Setting up the Chaos Vehicles Plugin | Epic Developer Community
I got it working halfway. Two Problems arise.
The first:

The car is floating above the ground. When moving it around it seems like in the center of it there is a beam that stops it from reaching the ground. However in the "Player Collision" Screen I cant see anything.
The other problem can also be seen in the picture: The back wheels rotate in every direction possible, not only in the "driving direction".
I have looked through the tutorial again and compared my settings to the vehicle template, but I have not found any significant differences.
My Pawn just looks like this:
so there should not be any sphere collider or something like it underneath.
That pawn is set in a custom GameMode as the standard pawn.
Does anyone here maybe have a clue what may be going on here?
Thank you in advance.
Best Regards
Severin
